How to calculate the GPS uncertainty to a given location
I'm writing software to calculate the GPS uncertainty to a given location.
Most GPS (GNSS) receivers report a Longitude Uncertainty and Latitude Uncertainty. I simply assumed this would interpret into an oval of the form:
r = LongUncert * cos (bearing) + LatUncert * sin (bearing)

(Since I'm using trig functions here, let's assume bearing starts from 0 (East) and increment counter clock wise.  For example 90 for North and 180 for West.)
But someone mentioned it sounded more like a rectangle of uncertainty.  The the height being the latitude uncertainty and the width being the longitude uncertainty.  I could see that too.
The application: I would like to tell the user they are a certain distance from a long/lat coordinate and supply a +/- number of meters of uncertainty.

Why a close vote? I checked and there are plenty of GPS questions in stackoverflow.com. But none address this particular application (how to calculate the uncertainty along a given vector to a target).

Looks like the stackexchange related question look up is not so great. GPS uncertainty has been talked about before. Looking back at stackexchange using google I see this and this. But I don't see where anyone is calculating one uncertainty measurement from a latitude and longitude uncertainty value.
